# php include statement executes just one instance of the WHILE loop

Tags: php, syntax, include

I thoroughly researched the topic, but my beginner coding skills are wondering why PHP renders only one line of the WHILE loop contained in the INCLUDE script.

To make your answering easy, here are the elements of my problem:

A) call to include the php script:

```
include ("/DEMO/HtmlTabela.php");
```

B) Contents of the INCLUDE script:

```
<?php 

$BrojRedova = 5;

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>Pozdrav</td>";
echo "<td>Ime</td>";
echo "<td>Prezime</td>";
echo "<td>Preduzece</td>";
echo "</tr>";

// Petlja za automatsko popunjavanje redova HTML tabele upotrebom PHP-a
$brojac = 0;
while($brojac<5) {
        echo "<td>Gospodin</td>";
        echo "<td>Daniel</td>";
        echo "<td>Andric</td>";
        echo "<td>PPB</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $brojac++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

C) Result

Pozdrav Ime Prezime Preduzece
Gospodin    Daniel  Andrić  PPB

D) Problem is, I wrote the WHILE loop to get this result:

Pozdrav Ime Prezime Preduzece
Gospodin    Daniel  Andric  PPB
Gospodin    Daniel  Andric  PPB
Gospodin    Daniel  Andric  PPB
Gospodin    Daniel  Andric  PPB
Gospodin    Daniel  Andric  PPB

Comment: It may be working correctly, but you appear to have an HTML error, which could cause issues with seeing the display of the information. You are missing the opening `<tr>` element in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `echo('<tr>');` at the beginning of the while loop to start the table row. Examining the HTML output of your script is a great help in debugging your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your original code.I think you forgot to place `echo('<tr>');` inside while loop. You can use it like in the following code.

```
while($brojac<5) {
    echo('<tr>');
    echo "<td>Gospodin</td>";
    echo "<td>Daniel</td>";
    echo "<td>Andric</td>";
    echo "<td>PPB</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $brojac++;
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer [(see How to accept SO answers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) and upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you [(see How to upvote on Stack Overflow?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Daniel Just like Lemon said. That's how Stack rolls. Otherwise, others may think your question is still open and unresolved and may be tempted to post more answers.